# White screen when updating to ionic 2 beta 8

Tags: angularjs, cordova, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am in the process of upgrading our ionic 2 application several beta version. While in the process of upgrading from beta 7 to beta 8, I got to the point when the application would build - but now I have nothing but a white screen on load. I am getting console logs just fine, indicating things are at least initially loading as they should, but I am getting nothing displayed in the browser or in the iOS emulator.

Here's my app.ts:

```
import {Platform, Storage, LocalStorage, ionicBootstrap} from 'ionic-angular';
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {StatusBar} from 'ionic-native';
import {TabsPage} from './pages/tabs/tabs';
import {RouteConfig} from '@angular/router-deprecated';
import {IntroPage} from './pages/intro/intro';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Component({    
  template: '<ion-nav [root]="root"></ion-nav>'
})
@RouteConfig([
  {path: '/', component: IntroPage, as: 'Intro'}
])

export class AppComponent {

  public rootPage: any = TabsPage;
  public platform: any;
  public discountData: any;
  public local: any;
  public root: any;

  constructor(platform: Platform) {
    this.platform = platform;
    this.root = IntroPage;

    platform.ready().then(() => {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
      StatusBar.styleLightContent();
      StatusBar.backgroundColorByHexString("#009EDD");
    });

  }

}

ionicBootstrap(AppComponent, [
  DataPersistence
  ], {
    backButtonText: 'Back',
    backButtonIcon: 'ios-arrow-back',
    iconMode: 'md',
    tabSubPages: false,
    modalEnter: 'modal-slide-in',
    modalLeave: 'modal-slide-out',
    tabbarPlacement: 'bottom',
    pageTransition: 'ios',
  }
);
```

Going from beta 6 to 7, I was having issues with the router that were causing similar problems and had to move to the deprecated angular router for the time being. I'm unsure if it's related to that.

Does anyone have any insight into what could be causing this error-less white screen?

Comment: have you looked at the changelog? (in the upgrade from beta 7 to 8 section), it might be useful: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: Yep, and as far as I know I followed it word for word. It's very useful when things go perfect, but if they don't there isn't a lot of info as to what to do with it.

Comment: I absolutely agree. I believe it is due that Ionic 2 is still under development. Think about it, Angular 2 was released only a few days ago. Ionic 2 is still far from being perfect. Anyway, why not upgrading to beta 10 or 11?

Comment: I am, but there are so many breaking changes between the versions doing it more than a version at a time makes it hard to track where things went wrong when they do go wrong.